# What is solution to this integration of $sec^{2}x$, limits of integration being from $\pi/6$ to $\pi/2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

What is solution to this integration of $sec^{2}x$, limits of integration being from $\pi/6$ to $\pi/2$. The pi/2 screws the integration. What should i do ?

This is part of integration of double integral over a region, in cartesian coordinated no problem arose, but when i changed to polars, this integral showed up

Original question is

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwqJS.png

I solved this with cartesian, i will be thankful if someone does it in polar coordinates

Comment: The integral indeed blows us at $\pi/2$. Hence diverges. But which is the initial question ? The picture is not uploaded.

Comment: @Tolaso here is http://i.imgur.com/6QN2CJV.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\displaystyle I = \int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sec^2 xdx = \left[\tan x\right]_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} = \lim_{a\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}}\tan (a)-\tan \left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right).$

Comment: $$I =\cdots {\color{red}-}\tan \left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right) {\color{red}+}\lim_{a\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}}\tan (a)$$

It is the reverse.